# Does `lockstep` argument only affect sensor plugin?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo [offers an option](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=lockstep_physics_sensors&cat=sensors), `--lockstep` to update sensor readings using  the exactly `upate_rate` defined by sensor plugin description.  Does other kinds of plugins, such as world or model plugin, can be affected by this option?

I think  it can. Because these plugins also define the`OnUpdate` method, which in my opinion it is affected by the `upate_rate` parameter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26473/does-%60lockstep%60-argument-only-affect-sensor-plugin?/) by [jianwu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40876/jianwu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A plugin may or may not use the update event. A plugin could, for example, spin up a thread and perform asynchronous operations. You'll have to look at each plugin that you're using to see if it use the `update` event.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2021-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jianwu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40876/jianwu/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thank for your answer!  So you mean that if a plugin has the `update` event, it will be affected by `--lockstep` argument?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2021-01-27**:
Yes, the lockstep will control when Gazebo takes a simulation step, which in turn affects when events are triggered.

**Comment by [jianwu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40876/jianwu/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thanks a lot.